# C# Program to Get a Number and Display the Sum of the Digits

Tags: c#

I'm just beginning to learn C# and I can't figure out why this example problem is laid out this way. Maybe I'm not understanding the basics of how the order of operations works. Can someone explain how the "while" portion of this program works? I don't understand what "num = num / 10" does when num is not referenced after this line. Does it affect the previous line? Thanks for any insight.

```
/*
 * C# Program to Get a Number and Display the Sum of the Digits 
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Program
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num, sum = 0, r;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (num != 0)
        {
            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : "+sum);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: num is referenced after division, it is just not in same loop iteration. It is used in next loop iteration (starting from evaluating while condition). It does not affect previous line in the current loop iteration but it does affect in next iteration.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it affect the previous line?

If by previous you mean the `while condition`, then yes, and just affect the check by next check in the loop.

the code just do a summary of all the digital numbers

like if your input is

```
1235
```

then the output will be

```
1+2+3+5 = 11
```

The while loop will forever be executed if the condition is true by

```
num != 0
```

And in the loop, you just modify the `num` so that it will be compared to `0` again in the **next** condition check.

If it's always true ie always

```
num != 0
```

Then you will get an infinite loop, which is possible in some condition.

And welcome to the coding world :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Example We Input a Number "123"

When it goes to the condition While Number(123) != (is not equal to) 0 Then it will perform the code. 
First get the remainder by using modulus %. 
Second get the Whole number by using division.
Third Get the sum.

1.) r = num % 10 | The value of r now is 3
2.) num = num / 10 | The value of num now is 12.
3.) sum = sum + r | The value of sum here is 0 + the remainder 3.

It will go the the while statement again. Is the number(12) != (is not equal to) 0 then it will perform the code.

Take note the value now of Num is 12 ok.
Perform again the code.

1.) r = num % 10 | The value of r now is 2
2.) num = num / 10 | The value of num now is 1.
3.) sum = sum + r | The value of sum here now is 3 + the remainder now is 2.

So the sum now is 5. Then it will loop again because Num now is equal to 1. Then 
Perform the code again.

I think this explains the best for you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will end up in an endless loop in that Code. Using while loop it always execute the code inside the while loop as long as your `num` variable has a value.

And inside your while loop code your `sum` value has no connection with the formula.

```
r = num % 10;
num = num / 10;
sum = sum + r;
```

Instead change it to this where `sum` is set to value of `num / 10`

```
r = num % 10;
sum = num / 10;
sum = sum + r;
```

And use `if` statement instead. Because every time the user input number it is guaranteed that it is only executed once. so no need for while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num, sum = 0, r;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (num != 0)
            {
                /* Important: The logic behind is to add the numbers from the last one
                 * to the first one.
                 * 
                 * For example, 123 will be added in this way: 3 + 2 + 1
                 * We will use number 123 as example.*/

                /* Comment: 
                 * 
                 * 1st run: 123 % 10, remainder will be 3. Anything modulus 10 will 
                 * always get the final digit. Now, we have r = 3, which will be used 
                 * in the final sum below.
                 * 
                 * 2nd run: 12 % 10, remainder will be 2. Now, we have r = 2, which 
                 * will be used in the final sum below.
                 * 
                 * 3rd run: 1 % 10, remainder will be 1. Now, we have r = 1, which will 
                 * be used in the final sum below.
                 */
                r = num % 10;

                /* Comment: 
                 *
                 * 1st run: 123 / 10, answer will be 12. If you are wondering why it 
                 * isn't 12.3, then it is because the datatype in used is "int", so the 
                 * answer will always be a round number, so 12.3 in round number will 
                 * be 12, which is the 2 numbers that have not been added, so now, 
                 * num = 12, and we have managed to discard 3 because we no longer need 
                 * it because it will be added in the final sum below.
                 * 
                 * 2nd run: 12 / 10, again answer is not 1.2, but num = 1. 
                 * We have managed to discard 2 because we no longer need it because it 
                 * will be added in the final sum below.
                 * 
                 * 3rd run: 1 / 10, again answer is not 0.1, but num = 0. 
                 * We have managed to discard 1 because we no longer need it because it 
                 * will be added in the final sum below. This will be the final run.
                 */
                num = num / 10;

                /* Comment: 
                 * 1st run: 0 + 3 (1st run remainder)
                 * 2nd run: 3 + 2 (2nd run remainder)
                 * 3rd run: 5 + 1 (3rd run remainder)
                 */
                sum = sum + r;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of Digits of the Number : " + sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

And yes, the "num" variable is used by the "while" loop to check on the current condition. If the "num" is not "0", then the logic will continue to run. Hope this helps.